# How to compare two list values and round them to first list values without adding them internally

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, linq

I have two list values

```
Example:
first list total 285, second list total 220

first List values:
x1 = 55
x2 = 105
x3 = 100
x4 = 25

second List values:
y1 = 25
y2 = 25
y3 = 50
y4 = 120
```

If second list value y1(25) is not equal to first list value x1(55). Then second list y1 should be compared and it should borrow 25 from y2 to become 55. 
Still y1 is lack of 5 to become 55. So it borrows 5 from y3. Then

```
 y1 = 25, 25, 5  (total is 55).
    y2 = 0
    y3 = 45
    y4 = 120
```

Now again y2 need to be rounded with x2 to become 105. So final values are below and the parts should not be added. They need to be as individual only like (25,
    25, 5) in the second list y1 as individual collection or list. Now

```
y1 = 25, 25, 5  ->(total is 55)
y2 = 45 , 60 (45 shifts from y3 & 60 shifts from y4)
y3 = 60 (balance in y4 shifts to y3 subtracted from y4(120))
y4 = 0
```

[Link here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OonBiH)
Same case if second list y1 is 75 then the extra 20 should be carried to y2, y3 and so on.
How to apply this in C#. Need best way to do this.
 Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What code have you written so far? Please add that to the post.

Comment: @Sunil can do this using if conditions but i want better way with Linq or any good procedure.

Comment: What if `x1 < y1`, say `x1 = 55` and `y1 = 65`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko then 10 is carried to y2. means y2 = 10, 25. y1 becomes 55. Again if y2 is greater than x2, balance will be carried to y3. then y3 = y3 , (transferred value from y2).

Answer (score 2):

Add all numbers in second list say Total.
And for each element in second list assign same value as in first list by subtracting from total, remaining whatever is in total will go to last element in second list.

Here Total = 220, y1 = 220- 55 (total=165) = , y2 = 165-105  (total = 60), y3 = 60-50 (total = 10) , y4 = 10

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with the following code after understanding your requirements. Hope this helps. Please try it out.

```
int[] x = new int[] {55, 105, 100, 25};
int[] y = new int[] {25, 25, 50, 120};
List<int>[] r = new List<int>[]{new List<int>(), new List<int>(), new List<int>(), new List<int>()};

for(int i = 0; i < x.Count(); i++){
    if (x[i] < y[i]) {
        y[i+1] = y[i] - x[i];
        y[i] = x[i];
        r[i].Add(y[i]);
    } else if (x[i] > y[i]) {
        r[i].Add(y[i]);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < y.Count(); j++){
            if (x[i] == y[i] + y[j]) {
                y[i] = x[i];
                y[j] = 0;
                r[i].Add(y[j]);
                break;
            } else if(x[i] > y[i] + y[j]) {
                y[i]+=y[j];
                r[i].Add(y[j]);
                y[j]=0;
            } else {
                y[j] = y[i] + y[j] - x[i];
                r[i].Add(x[i]-y[i]);
                y[i] = x[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        r[i].Add(y[i]);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", y));
for(int i = 0; i < r.Count(); i++){
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", r[i]));
}
```

This stores all the steps involved in r for each y.

Comment: values should be splitting in each List item like y1 will contain 25, 25, 5. y2 is 45 and 60. so on. https://dotnetfiddle.net/OonBiH

Comment: Do you want them as a list of strings?

Comment: yes. I can use them as List only not combine values.

Comment: @alexdave check the edited version. I hope thats what you want.